# Tasks -v- Parallel.Invoke

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing, task

Whilst both of these methods work for me, and without too much difference in operation time, I'm wondering which is the "better" method to use and what people's experiences of both are.

I have two Subs which run two completely separate routines in parallel; lets call them Sub1 and Sub2 as my imagination isn't fired up yet today!

I used to use Parallel.Invoke like this:

```
Parallel.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf Sub1), New Action(AddressOf Sub2)
```

This worked fine. Then I discovered threads and tasks... :-)

I changed it to:

```
Dim task As Task
Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)

task = New Task(Sub() Sub1())
tasks.Add(task)
task.Start()

task = New Task(Sub() Sub2())
tasks.Add(task)
task.Start()
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray)
```

Again, it seems to work fine.

I had thought about looking into background workers, but compared to Tasks, these seem unnecessarily complicated!

Whilst both "work", I'm interested to know what people regard as the "acceptable" or "best" one to use is.

Comment: `Parallel.Invoke` uses `Tasks` internally anyway.  It even calls `Task.WaitAll`.  It's just a simplified API for simple scenarios. Using `Tasks` directly provides more flexibility but also more complexity.  While it's not a big deal, you can see that your second code snippet is more complex than the first so, with no benefit to the longer code, the shorter is better for being short.  Nothing wrong with using the second though and, if you use `Tasks` directly in other scenarios, it may feel more consistent.  Six of one, Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Thanks for that. Given they both do the same thing, I may revert to the invoke method. Thanks